# How to expand a new added node in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a `TreeView` in my form, I need to add programmatically a new node on particolar mouse event. Then I need to expand the tree just to the new added node. I try to call the function `Expand()` on the new added node but I does not works.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
TreeNodeCollection tree = treeViewProtocolli.Nodes["Radice"].Nodes["ModBus"].Nodes;
if (tree != null)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    node.Text = "MBRTU";
    node.Name = "MBRTU";
    node.Tag = "BASE";
    node.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    tree.Add(node);

TreeNode skBase = treeViewProtocolli.Nodes["Radice"].Nodes["ModBus"].Nodes["MBRTU"];
    if(skBase != null)
    {
        TreeNode sknode = new TreeNode();
        sknode.Text = nome + " -> [Slave = " + slave + " | Indirizzo = " + indirizzo +
                " | Funzione = " + funzione + " | Abilitato = " + abil + " | Lunghezza blocco = " + lunghezza + "]";

        sknode.Name = "MBRTU";

        skBase.Nodes.Add(sknode);

        sknode.Expand();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`EnsureVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible(v=vs.110).aspx) method of node. It ensures that the tree node is visible, expanding tree nodes and scrolling the tree view control as necessary.

For example:

```
var node = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("something");
node.EnsureVisible();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeNode.Expand()` on every node from the root to the leaf you wanted to be expanded, using Expand on the leaf node or the node you want to expand make only the node itself to show its subchildren.
ex. root -> nextnode1 -> somennode2 
If you want to be expanded truout somennode2 you should expand all of its parrent nodes (root.expand,nextnode1.expand and if you want you last node expanded somennode2.expand.

Comment: You don't need to expand all parents manually, instead you can call [`EnsureVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible(v=vs.110).aspx) method of node. It ensures that the tree node is visible, expanding tree nodes and scrolling the tree view control as necessary like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768089/3110834).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks to all those who answered me.

I've find an easy solution: first I build a `List` with all the parent of the desidered node to expand, then i browse the list backwards to expand each TreeNode. This is my code.

```
private void OpenTree(TreeNode node)
{
    List<TreeNode> parents = new List<TreeNode>();
    parents.Add(node); // Add the actual node to expand

    TreeNode actPa = node;
    do
    {
        actPa = actPa.Parent;
        if (actPa != null)
            parents.Add(actPa);     // Add all the parent node
    }
    while (actPa != null);

    if(parents.Count > 0)
    {
        for(int iRep = parents.Count - 1; iRep >= 0; iRep --)
        {
            parents[iRep].Expand();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do with above code can be simply achieved using `EnsureVisible` method of the node, like what I did in the answer.